# Why using $lt with compound index is so slow (with index sorting UP)?

Tags: mongodb

I have a compound index, I built it for a specific query following the general rule: equality, then sort, then range.
A general representation of my data:

```
[
{"status": "finished", "counter": 2, "time": -1},
{"status": "waiting",  "counter": 0, "time": 0},
{"status": "waiting",  "counter": 3, "time": 1},
{"status": "waiting",  "counter": 3, "time": 1},
{"status": "waiting",  "counter": 4, "time": 3}
]
```

My query:
`{status: "waiting", counter: {$lt: 3, $gte: 0}}`
sort: `{date: -1}`

I tried building the index in many ways, but the one that fits most in my opinion is:
`{status: -1, date: -1, counter: 1}`

My thought is, the status "waiting" is the one I really want,
and it will be sorted by date, and the counter is sorted UP so it will be easy to fetch the first X documents. But it isn't.. it's examining hunreds of thousands of documents to fetch only 1500.

This query takes too long with this index, and scans WAY too many documents.. (about 1000 docs for 1 result)

I'd love a better explanation because I couldn't figure out what I did wrong with this index,
Should I just use the second query ?

Comment: When using `$lt`, indexBounds are set to neg-infinity to 3 (excl). Maybe changing the filter to `{status: "new", counter: {$lt: 3, $gte: 0}}` helps. With the small sample data set, there is not really a difference in examined index keys and docs though.

Comment: @Markus I'm sorry my question was wrong. I edited, and I will try to provide more sample data..